# use Spline for getting data lineage with Dababricks without mongodb

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using Databricks with Azure environment and trying to use the  Spline libaray to get data lineage.

https://absaoss.github.io/spline/

However the document is not very clear and I am not able to figure out where the output file is generated.

```
import za.co.absa.spline.core.SparkLineageInitializer._
System.setProperty("spline.mode", "REQUIRED")
System.setProperty("spline.persistence.factory", "za.co.absa.spline.persistence.hdfs.HdfsPersistenceFactory")
System.setProperty("spline.hdfs.file.name", "/user/test/output")
spark.enableLineageTracking()

// Enable the tracking 
import za.co.absa.spline.core.SparkLineageInitializer._
spark.enableLineageTracking()
```

after this I don't see any file created.

I tried using ADLS path as well, however no luck.

**adls path**

> adl://azueus2devadlsdatalake.azuredatalakestore.net/aaa/test

Would someone please let me know what should I change or If don't provide path where the file would be created.

Comment: Take a look at this article where the author uses Spline, Event Hub and Apache Atlas
https://medium.com/@reenugrewal/data-lineage-tracking-using-spline-on-atlas-via-event-hub-6816be0fd5c7